# Is there any function that can display/ highlight detected haar-cascade features of a face?

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

I am using python and opencv. Code below is working fine. I am detecting faces and eyes. Is it possible to to show/display detected features by haar_cascade ?

Thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("models/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("models/haarcascade_eye.xml")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x + w, y + h), (255,0,0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        print(y,h,x,w)

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.1, 18)

        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            # cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex,ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0,255,0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)


    # plt.imshow(frame)
    # plt.show()

    cv2.imshow("Webcam Stream", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
```

Comment: for (x, y, w, h) in cars:????????????  cars?????

Comment: there's a (c++) visualization tool for haar / lbp features [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/apps/visualisation) like this: ![](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/visualisation_video.png)